# JavaFX Concurrency - why does the listing not work?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, javafx

I am trying to learn JavaFX Concurrency. For this purpose I tried to use the YouTube Tutorial on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wOtGPJBUAVs

But this does not work with my example and I can't find out why..

Thanks a lot for your help!!

```
public class JavaFXConcurrency extends Application {

private Service<Void> backgroundThread;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    Label label = new Label("Welcome");
    label.setLayoutX(50);
    label.setLayoutY(50);
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");


    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        backgroundThread = new Service<Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Task createTask() {
                return new Task() {

                    @Override
                    protected Object call() throws Exception {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++) {
                            updateMessage("i: " + i);
                        }
                        return null;
                    }

                };
            }
        };
    });

     backgroundThread.setOnSucceeded((WorkerStateEvent event) -> {
         System.out.println("Job Done");
    });
    label.textProperty().bind(backgroundThread.messageProperty());
    backgroundThread.restart();

    AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
    root.getChildren().addAll(btn, label);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Comment: Please define "does not work".

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you create first `backgroundThread` only after btn click, so you can't use this lines:

```
backgroundThread.setOnSucceeded((WorkerStateEvent event) -> {
    System.out.println("Job Done");
});

label.textProperty().bind(backgroundThread.messageProperty());
```

Because you never clicked the button and `backgroundThread` is still `null`. There are several ways to refactore this code to make it work, and here is 1 of them:(The easiest one is to put all `backgroundThread` realted code in  `btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {}`)

```
public class JavaFXConcurrency extends Application {
    private Service<Void> backgroundThread;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        Label label = new Label("Welcome");
        label.setLayoutX(50);
        label.setLayoutY(50);
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");

        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            backgroundThread = new Service<Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Task createTask() {
                    return new Task() {

                        @Override
                        protected Object call() throws Exception {
                            for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++) {
                                updateMessage("i: " + i);
                            }
                            return null;
                        }
                    };
                }
            };
            backgroundThread.setOnSucceeded((WorkerStateEvent e) -> {
                System.out.println("Job Done");
            });
            label.textProperty().bind(backgroundThread.messageProperty());
            backgroundThread.restart();
        }); // <-- HERE IS CLOSE BRACKETS OF btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {

        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
        root.getChildren().addAll(btn, label);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args);}
}
```